# If $Z=1/X$, is $E(Z)=\int 1/x \ f_X \ dx$?

Tags: probability

Let $Z=1/X$, where $f_X(x)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      x, & 0<x<1 \\
      1/2, & 1<x<2 \\
\end{array} 
\right.$

How do we do $E(Z)$?

I would do with a change of variables, i.e., $E(Z)=\int z f_Z(z) \ dz$. However, I've seen a resolution where they would do $E(Z)=\int \frac{1}{x} f_X(x) \ dx$ which doesn't seem to be consistent with the change of variables...

Am I correct?

Comment: @MANMAID typo. It wasn't supposed to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition,
$$
E(Z) = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{1}{x}\, f_X(x) \, \mathrm{d}x \, .
$$
Since $X$ is positive, the change of variables $z=1/x$ in the previous integral is $C^1$-diffeomorphic:
\begin{aligned}
E(Z) = \int_\mathbb{R^+} z\, f_X(1/z) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2} \, .
\end{aligned}
Thus, with $f_Z(z) = f_X(1/z)/z^2$, the proposed solution is consistent with the change of variable.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I had a mistake in my calculations. thanks